# Semantics of turning list into string

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Many programming languages, including Python, support an operation like this:

```
", ".join(["1","2","3"])
```

which returns the string

```
"1, 2, 3"
```

I understand that this is the case, but I don't understand the design decision behind it - surely it would be more semantically valid to perform the `join` operation on the list, like so:

```
["1","2","3"].join(", ")
```

If anyone could explain the design decision and shed some light on it I'd appreciate it.

Edit: It looks like Javascript has the `join` method on the list; if anyone has examples for which convention particular languages follow, feel free to comment/answer about the choice in that particular language too.

Comment: Note that your example *doesn't work* in python.  The list must contain only strings.

Comment: Lists are, in some sense, a lower level (more basic part of) of the language.  so strings know about lists, but lists don't know about strings.

Comment: I've edited the syntax to reflect that - the question was more about the overall semantics than that particular operation though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python, there are a few arguments against it.  First, if it is a string method that accepts an arbitrary iterable, then you only need to support the `join` method on string objects and it automagically works with anything iterable.  Otherwise, custom iterable objects would also need to support a `join` method, etc. etc.

consider:

```
", ".join(["1","2","3"])
", ".join(("1","2","3"))
", ".join(str(x) for x in xrange(1,4))
", ".join({'1':None,'2':None,'3':None})
", ".join({'1','2','3'})  #set literal syntax -- python2.7+
", ".join("123")
```

6 different types all supported very simply by a single method (and I've only touched builtin types).

Second, you can only `join` a list if everything in it is a `basestring` type.  It seems silly to provide a method on a list which would raise an exception if you used it on a list with the wrong contents -- At least, the API here seems somewhat tricky (to me).  Of course, you could argue that `list.remove` can raise an exception if called with the wrong arguments.  And that's true -- But that in general you're only removing a single item.  It operates on a lower level than `join` should.  Of course, this argument is weaker than the first one I proposed, so if you don't like it, just fall back on argument 1.